# how to remove a specific word(node) in linked list

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to delete a node, but it's still there when I print the list. I don't know what the problem is.

```
public void REMOVEWORD(String word) {
    //declare and initialize a help pointer 
    Word helpPtr = head;
    while (helpPtr.getNext() != null) {
        if (helpPtr.getNext().getWord().equals(word)) {
            helpPtr.setNext(helpPtr.getNext().getNext());
         //subtract the frequency of the word to be deleted from the list
            int total = helpPtr.getNext().getFrequency() - countWords;
            break;
        }
        helpPtr = helpPtr.getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: To start off with, you never actually check the value in "head"; you immediately skip it by going straight to `getNext()`.

Comment: thanks! the method now is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually correct, the missing part is just you forgot to check the head of the linkedlist.

> I have a problem that I want to delete a node but it still there when I print the list

I am not sure why you can't delete a node. Check the values since maybe they differ in their case(one is lower case and the other is upper case). But if you don't care about the cases then just change your insert method and convert all the to be inserted words into lower/upper case.

I just made a little adjustment of your code. Refer below:

```
    public void REMOVEWORD(String word) {
        // declare and initialize a help pointer
        Word helpPtr = head;

        // ADD THIS PART (START)
        if (helpPtr.getWord().equals(word)) { // check if the head is the to be removed word
            head = helpPtr.getNext(); // if true then set head to head.getNext()
            return;
        }
        // ADD THIS PART (END)

        while (helpPtr.getNext() != null) { // iterate through the linkedlist
            if (helpPtr.getNext().getWord().equals(word)) { // check if the next node is the word to be removed
                Word next = helpPtr.getNext().getNext(); // if true then get the next node of the next node
                helpPtr.setNext(next); // set the next of the current node to the acquire node above
                // subtract the frequency of the word to be deleted from the list
                // int total = helpPtr.getNext().getFrequency() - countWords; // NOT SURE WHAT
                // THIS CODE WILL DO SO I JUST COMMENTED IT OUT
                break;
            }
            helpPtr = helpPtr.getNext();
        }
    }
```